# Installing fTools and Table manager

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation, ubuntu

I've just make clean install of QGIS Lisboa under Ubuntu Precise. Latest QGIS version under Windows XP is very unstable (crashes every few minuter while editing shp file).

After new installation there are some problems for me:

1. I can't see or add independent repositories. So I can't add them under "Repositories" tab.

Can I add them anyway?

What I need is Table Manager at least. Possibility of install some other plugins could be useful as well.

2. I can't find "Join attributes" under fTools menu (it was the same problem after upgrading to Lisboa under Win XP, but deleting fTools directory and reinstalling this plugin solve problem but only under Win XP).

So, I can't work under Windows due to crashes nor under Ubuntu.

Could you help me to make QGIS fully functional under Ubuntu?

Comment: Open a Terminal and launch qgis by typing 'qgis'. You will see some output messages which may give you clue what's wrong. You can try the following commands to fix any permission issues. sudo chmod 755 ~/.qgis;sudo chown -R <your username> ~/.qgis

Comment: Here is terminal info: <code> Warning: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "Właściwości projektu..." under id 125 
Warning: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::fillLayoutItem(DBusMenuLayoutItem*, QMenu*, int, int, const QStringList&): No id for action 
Warning: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::fillLayoutItem(DBusMenuLayoutItem*, QMenu*, int, int, const QStringList&): No id for action 
Warning: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::fillLayoutItem(DBusMenuLayoutItem*, QMenu*, int, int, const QStringList&): No id for action </code>

Answer (score 2):

ad 1. In the 1.8.0 release - by default - you only get the new plugin repository but you can add any other repository you know using the "Add ..." button. Table Manager seems to be hosted on http://pyqgis.org/repo/contributed

Be aware that with the new release (and up to date GDAL) **you don't need Table Manager to delete Shapefile columns** anymore. It's now accessible through the attribute table dialog.

ad 2. Join attributes in ftools has been removed because there is a new Join incorporated in layer properties. This has been discussed in previous questions.

PS: Please report crashes on the bug tracker - otherwise developers won't know about them and they will go unfixed.